# Position fixed in a group list (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a group list and I'm trying to make them position fixed.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Quem-somos</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Reserve agora</strong></a>
    </div>
</div><!--/span-->
```

And I tried to setup this in my CSS:

```
#sidebar {
   position: fixed;
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

I fixed but not in the left side of my page. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you do position:fixed it defaults fixing to the top left.

If you want it to the right do::

```
#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using margin properties, to fix your div tag as you want within the page. Margin properties can help you align the div tag as you want it to be.